# The grammar of a language of a NFA state diagram - Antlr v4

Tags: null, antlr4, grammar, finite-automata

I am trying to write the grammer of the following NFA diagram
[image: Coffee machine state diagram]

My code is

```
grammar LTFA;

rS: 'Start' rA | EOF;

rA: 'Select_coffe' rB;

rB: 'Enter_money' rC | 'Cancel' rS;

rC:  'More_money_needed' rC | 'Refund' rE | 'Right_amount_of_money' rD;

rD: 'Change' rC | 'Done' | 'Done' rS;

rE: 'End' | 'End' rS;

WS: ( ' ' | '\t' | '\n')->skip;
```

The problem is the language does not accept a null string(empty), how can I make is accept null??

here is the error I got

[image: The error]

Comment: Can you post specific code or a specific invocation of grun where you feed in an empty string and it's not accepted (plus the syntax error message you're getting)? When I try to parse an empty string using your grammar and the starting rule `rS`, it works fine.

Comment: @sepp2k okey done I got a message says "no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'"

Comment: Okay, this is strange. I get the same error when I run this using the IntelliJ ANTLR plugin, but when I run ANTLR + grun in the command line, it works fine.

Comment: The plugin and generated parser use two different `Parser` classes: `org.antlr.v4.tool.GrammarParserInterpreter : Parser` and `LTFAParser : Parser`. They parse using different machines, which you can see if you read the Java code. It seems the plugin interpreter has a bug because the tokens lexed are the same between plugin and generated parser. Why did you define a grammar with multiple rules? An Antlr rule is equivalent to an ATN, aka NFA. In other words, this could likely be defined via one rule using EBNF, not identical, but likely refactored equivalent to the NFA you defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task is probably not possible to accomplish. While you can generate a state machine (ATN, NFA, DFA) from a grammar, it's not possible to do the reverse, because states are not rules and you cannot create rules from only states and transitions. However, you are trying here to use grammar rules in place of states.

Let's take a look at an example, your rule `rB`:

```
rB: 'Enter_money' rC | 'Cancel' rS;
```

What your state diagram says you want is:

1. We have to be in state Q2.
2. We enter the input "Enter_money".
3. We end up in state Q3.

or

2. We enter the input "cancel".
3. We end up in state Q0.

The rule however says:

1. Match the input "Enter_money".
2. Then match rule `rC` (which requires more input)

or

1. Match the input "Cancel".
2. Then match rule ' rS' (which requires the whole chain to match again).

While you can certainly take a set of nodes and put them in a rule to execute for certain input, you will not be able to direct the parser interpreter (or state walker) to end up in a specific state (like the start state once a purchase was finished or cancelled).

Answer (score 0):

When running this code:

```java
LTFALexer lexer = new LTFALexer(CharStreams.fromString(""));
LTFAParser parser = new LTFAParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));

System.out.println(parser.rS().toStringTree(parser));
```

I get the following output in my console:

```
(rS <EOF>)
```

and no errors are displayed.

And a test in Python results in the same:

```py
from antlr4 import *
from LTFALexer import LTFALexer
from LTFAParser import LTFAParser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lexer = LTFALexer(InputStream(''))
    parser = LTFAParser(CommonTokenStream(lexer))
    print(parser.rS().toStringTree(recog=parser))
```

then too, `(rS <EOF>)` is printed.

Comment: But it does not work using PyCharm  ANTLR plugin

Comment: Whenever you doubt results produced by a/the plugin, always test with some test class of your own: that way you're sure. I added a Python demo as well. The grammar accepts an empty string.